# CSS/HTML - Infinite scrolling slider problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a slider in which the goal is to have three different ads sliding left to right in an infinite loop.

I have created the slider like so:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div id="slider">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="one"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="two"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="three"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the CSS here:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px; 
  max-width: 500px; 
  height: 200px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider {
  width: 300%; 
  position: relative; 
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: 6s slide infinite; 
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {margin-left: 0}
  16.67% {margin-left: 0}
  33.33% {margin-left: -100%}
  50% {margin-left: -100%}
  66% {margin-left: -100%}
  75% {margin-left: -200%}
  100% {margin-left: -200%}
}

.box {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%; 
  float: left;
}

.box div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px; 
}

.one {
  background: green; 
}

.two {
  background: red; 
}

.three {
  background: blue; 
}
```

[Working JSBin](https://jsbin.com/picuvigoxo/edit?html,css,output)

#### The problem:

I cannot get the first slide to "reset", so I get the small flicker at the end of the animation where it resets. I have tried different methods, but to no avail. Optimally, I would be able to add an "invisible" keyframe to reset the position. Any ideas how this could work?

Answer (score 0):

You need add **animation-direction** and **animation-play-state** in css.
Update css for #slider like:

```
#slider {
  width: 300%; 
  position: relative; 
  overflow: hidden;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-direction:alternate;
  animation-play-state:running;
}
```

Result https://jsfiddle.net/Coderius/sqga89eo/

Or if need return for last slide to first slide change this:

```
#slider {
    width: 300%; 
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden;
    animation-name: slide;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    /* animation-direction:alternate; */
    /* animation-play-state:running; */

}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {margin-left: 0}
  16.67% {margin-left: 0}
  33.33% {margin-left: -100%}
  50% {margin-left: -100%}
  66% {margin-left: -100%}
  75% {margin-left: -200%}
  80% {margin-left: -200%}
  85% {margin-left: -200%}
  100% {margin-left: 0%}
}
```

Result - https://jsfiddle.net/Coderius/j2b3vm65/

Comment: Thanks, great input! The first solution with `animation-direction: alternate` was almost what I was looking for. Ideally though, the animation would *reset* like your 2nd example but being **invisible** for the duration (i.e. no fast sliding by being visible) so it looks like an infinite loop. Maybe this is not possible?

Comment: Glad I suggested useful options! Is there any visual example, what result do you need?

Comment: Here is a codepen of a similar example, as you can see the slider is always sliding right->left: `https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi` The code difference here is that this is using the `figure` element, which is not possible since I will not be using images, but `div` elements with content inside.